# Finite subgroup of infinite group

Tags: group-theory, infinite-groups

Let $G$ be an infinite order group. Let $H$ be its finite order subgroup. Then what we say about $H$? For example, $H$ is always cyclic or we have a group $G$ having finite subgroup $H$ which is not cyclic.

Comment: What do you mean, “Let $H$ be its finite order subgroup”? Do you mean the set of all elements of finite order? Usually called the torsion subgroup of $G$. Can be the whole thing (as $\Bbb Q/Bbb Z$) or only the identity (as $\Bbb Q$).

Comment: Consider the direct product $$\prod_{i=1}^{\infty}\Bbb Z_i.$$ It has more than one finite subgroup, despite being infinite.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any finite group is be a subgroup of some infinite group. Simply consider $G=H\times\mathbb{Z}$. In fact there's an infinite group having **all** finite groups (up to isomorphism) as subgroups. Simply take $G=\bigoplus H_i$ over all (up to isomorphism) finite groups $\{H_i\}$, which is a countable set.

And so not much can be said in such an extremely general case.

Comment: Ok i got it.... We take G = S_3 x Z which is infinite group.Then we  got finite order non cyclic subgroup S_3 x{0}